# How to make auto-complete work in AucTeX mode?

Tags: latex, auctex, auto-complete-mode

I want `auto-complete` (ac) to work when I am inside `AucTeX` mode.
I get all packages from MELPA by package installation.

This is my relevant code in `init.el` file:

```
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)   
(global-auto-complete-mode t)
```

as you can see, although I am setting `ac` globally it does not appear in `AucTeX`. However, by following instructions in this [emacswiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoCompleteSources), `ac` mode was displayed in status bar in `AucTeX` but non-functioning, no auto-completion by typing characters.

**Notes**
Emacs 24.4 under Windows 7 32bit and packages were updated.

Comment: Your problem is to make ac work together yasnippet or just alone, while in LaTex mode? In the latter case, I use ac with AUCTeX without much work.

Comment: 1st, I want to have `ac` do well with `auctex`. I mentioned `yasnippet` because I also use it to have some user-defined snippets in latex. So until you provide your code I cannot tell if `yas` will get in the way of `ac`.

Comment: Tone, please!  Try taking out `yasnippet` to see if autocomplete and AUCTeX work together as @giordano suggested.  If yes, then the problem is with the inclusion of `yasnippet`.  If so, it's probably your autocomplete setup.

Comment: We can forget about `yasnippet` I removed it from my init.el. The problem is most probably in the setup of `auctex` and `ac`.

Comment: @Dan I updated the question, to avoid complexity of adding the `yasnippet`.

Comment: See  a package by Christopher Monsanto https://github.com/monsanto/auto-complete-auctex. I haven't test it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After doing a long research in the web and careful examination of `ac` documentation with a lot of trials on my machine to examine code line by line, I came up with this solution that can have `yasnippet` working as well (optioinal) without any confict.

put this in your `init.el` or `.emacs` taking care of sequence:

```
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)

;; yasnippet code 'optional', before auto-complete
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)

;; auto-complete setup, sequence is important
(require 'auto-complete)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'latex-mode) ; beware of using 'LaTeX-mode instead
(require 'ac-math) ; package should be installed first 
(defun my-ac-latex-mode () ; add ac-sources for latex
   (setq ac-sources
         (append '(ac-source-math-unicode
           ac-source-math-latex
           ac-source-latex-commands)
                 ac-sources)))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-ac-latex-mode)
(setq ac-math-unicode-in-math-p t)
(ac-flyspell-workaround) ; fixes a known bug of delay due to flyspell (if it is there)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'org-mode) ; auto-complete for org-mode (optional)
(require 'auto-complete-config) ; should be after add-to-list 'ac-modes and hooks
(ac-config-default)
(setq ac-auto-start nil)            ; if t starts ac at startup automatically
(setq ac-auto-show-menu t)
(global-auto-complete-mode t)
```

**Notes:**
as mentioned in the [documentation](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#Introduction) of `ac`, the adding to `ac-modes` and hooks should be done before loading `(ac-config-default)`.

Some suggested to put some code to play with `TAB` key which I didn't need and do not recommend as it will somehow destroy something else later. However, I saw people put something like this at the end just before `global-auto-complete`:

```
(ac-set-trigger-key "TAB")
(ac-set-trigger-key "<tab>")
```

Until I added `(ac-flyspell-workaround)` auto-completion was too slow to think of using it in Auctex since I use flyspell. This bug was also mentioned in the documentation. Thanks!

**Bonus**
I was glad to know from the documentation, though not very clear how, that one can add a user-defined dictionary(ies)! I tried this and worked well.

add these two lines just after `require-auto-complete` line above:

```
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/.dict") ; make sure this folder exists
(add-to-list 'ac-user-dictionary-files "~/.emacs.d/.dict/custom-dict.txt") ; put any name to your `.txt` file
```

Now in your `.txt` file add your favorite candidates for completion. Save yourself from candidates fewer than 4-letter long, they don't worth it! Simply put words of your like separated by a line feed or `RET`.

Example of the contents in the `.txt` file:

```
inconsistencies
foobaremaild@foobar.com
do-not-put-your-password-here
long-line-in-any-programming-language-of-your-like
```

Enjoy auto-completion in LaTeX/AUCTeX with Emacs!

Comment: it would be nice if there would be an `elisp` function to throw any marked word in a buffer while writing into that `.txt` dictioinary on-the-fly and append it without much effort!

Answer (score 6):

As I told in my above comment, the package [**`auto-complete-auctex`**](https://github.com/monsanto/auto-complete-auctex) can also solve the problem. I tested both, and they both work nicely. It would be nice to compare the solution of **@doctorate** and the above package by giving screen-shots. If I write `$\sig$`, the code of doctorate give something like this

[image]

and that of the package `auto-complete-auctex` gives something like this

[image]

Added: I should mention that the solution of **@giordano** works as well, here a screen-shot:

[image]

Comment: I think `auto-complete` should be the main package while `auto-complete-auctex` might have some extra features. I will try it and report if necessary. Thanks

Comment: I have installed the package but I am unable to open the popup with the completions... How did you do it and is there some documentation on this one?

Comment: @Raven I'm not sure I have it "really" working. But if you add in the TAB key steps that doctorate said to avoid, pressing TAB makes it work (for me).

Answer (score 4):

The following is my `auto-complete` related configuration:

```
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)

;; Activate auto-complete for latex modes (AUCTeX or Emacs' builtin one).
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'latex-mode)

;; Activate ac-math.
(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(when (featurep 'auto-complete)
     ;; See https://github.com/vspinu/ac-math
     (require 'ac-math)
     (defun ac-latex-mode-setup ()       ; add ac-sources to default ac-sources
       (setq ac-sources
         (append '(ac-source-math-unicode ac-source-math-latex ac-source-latex-commands)
             ac-sources)))
     (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'ac-latex-mode-setup)))
```

As you can see, there is nothing special for AUCTeX, it's the standard configuration of `auto-complete`.  The configuration for `ac-math` is described on its web site.  If you don't use `ac-math`, the only sensible difference with your configuration is `(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'latex-mode)`.

Comment: -1: Use `package-initialize`.  You may not like it, but please don't recommend bad practices such as manual `load-path` management in your answers.

Comment: @lunaryorn I don't think I recommended bad practices, I clearly wrote it's a dirty hack just to load an auxiliary package.  I'll try to improve the answer using `package-initialize` later anyway.